# firebase thenable reference return handling

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

i am using angularfire2 and making  a push call to store a object. it looks like below:

**Click handler**

```
assignCode(){
    this.ddlSvc.assignCoupon(this.selItem.key, coupon).then(
      (resp) =>  {
                      console.log("user created with:" + resp)
                      const alert = this.core.createAlert('Confirmation', 'Coupon Assgined to customer!')
                      alert.present()

                 }
    )
  }
```

**angular service making call to firebase**

```
assignCoupon(key:string, coupon:Coupon){
    return this.db.list('/users/' + key + '/coupons').push(coupon)
  }
```

It works fine when the calling client user has the required permissions to push to this node. However, we are testing a case where calling client does not have the permissions. currently, when we fire this case we get all the error on the UI in a very ugly manner rather a nice popup as we are not handling it. So, how do we handle error part? as it is a thenable reference so on click handler function there is no . ".catch" to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the definition of `ThenableReference` (in Visual Studio Code, you would press Ctrl-T and then type `ThenableReference`), you should see something like [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/2f17ba02a3a139678b849cd53b2199156e5bc6d1/packages/firebase/index.d.ts#L568-L570):

```
  interface ThenableReference
    extends firebase.database.Reference,
      PromiseLike<any> {}
```

The part we care about is the `PromiseLike<any>`.  If you jump to definition on that, you should see [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b9bd0d9a3ff3e468302b4ad1179ca5ee802d1ded/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1296-L1304):

```
interface PromiseLike<T> {
    /**
     * Attaches callbacks for the resolution and/or rejection of the Promise.
     * @param onfulfilled The callback to execute when the Promise is resolved.
     * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
     * @returns A Promise for the completion of which ever callback is executed.
     */
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): PromiseLike<TResult1 | TResult2>;
}
```

Notice that `then` accepts an optional second callback that is called in case of error.  You should be able to use that in place of the `catch` method.